# tls1.2 handshake on tls1 record python ssl

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I've been trying to create a TLSv1.2 connection to a server with python's `ssl` module. I was able to change the handshake tls version to the one I wanted (TLSv1.2). But no matter how I tried to set up my SSLContext, I only able to create a Client Hello with a TLSv1 record layer.

I saw [this issue](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1689) that made me understand why I was failing but I'm quite stuck now. Because the server I'm trying to connect to only accept TLSv1.2 record layers and immediately ends the connection without error message if it is not. So is there a hidden way to change the record layer version or shall I look into other languages for more flexible implementation/try to do my own whacky implementation ?

`ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` returns `OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018` and I am running python 3.7.2

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ssl
import socket

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
context.set_ciphers("AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA")
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_COMPRESSION
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)

conn = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname="address")

conn.connect(('address', 443))

conn.close()
```

Thanks!

Comment: "I only able to create a Client Hello with a TLSv1 record layer. " what do you mean  exactly by that? In many cases it is simpler to just use `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS` (awfully called `ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23` previously, so it depends which version you are using) it will do what is necessary to select highest possible protocol, which also makes you future-proof when server will switch to TLS 1.3

Comment: Also the "record layer" version will always be 1.0 so do not be fooled by that if you look at it with tools at the network layer. See https://tls.ulfheim.net/ for an explanation with illustration. The client version will be another value inside the record (for the ClientHello) and that is the requested TLS version by client. But the outer message (record) will always be TLS 1.0 because this framing does not change between TLS versions.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek

I meant that with every settings I tried to change, the version of the record layer always stayed 1.0 (which is understandable now with your second comment)

so it means that the application that is connecting to the server does not follow the specification as it **does** [have a tls record layer version](https://i.imgur.com/VkcKtQo.png) of \x03\x03

thank you for your clear answer!

Comment: What server is this? See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#appendix-E : "Earlier versions of the TLS specification were not fully clear on
   what the record layer version number (TLSPlaintext.version) should
   contain when sending ClientHello (i.e., before it is known which
   version of the protocol will be employed).  Thus, TLS servers
   compliant with this specification MUST accept any value {03,XX} as
   the record layer version number for ClientHello." => buggy server

Comment: And next paragraph: "TLS clients that wish to negotiate with older servers MAY send any
   value {03,XX} as the record layer version number.  Typical values
   would be {03,00}, the lowest version number supported by the client,
   and the value of ClientHello.client_version.  No single value will
   guarantee interoperability with all old servers, but this is a
   complex topic beyond the scope of this document."

Comment: it's a game server that rolls "it's own" tls implementation. I just set up a socket proxy and change the record layer version to match what it wants and it works now.

the company that made this game is quite known for it's spaghetti code :')
@PatrickMevzek